# Speech-To-Text app in Windows Forms [offline]

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition, visual-studio-2019, offline

While I've been searching for APIs or any other info, I've found some variants:

- *Google API* (which uses web requests, therefore I don't need this),
- *Microsoft.Speech SDK* (which is pretty good for giving commands but not for regular speech),
- *System.Speech* (almost same as Microsoft.Speech).

For Microsoft.Speech I used [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/december/voice-recognition-speech-recognition-with-net-desktop-applications).
Is there any other way to make **offline** application with speech recognition like that do e.g. *Google Translator* or *Yandex Translator*? Or is there the only way: using default speech recognition and trying to "teach" him (constructing Grammars, Choices etc.)? :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on my research, Microsoft.Speech and System.Speech are better than other API. If you want to use it for regular speech, I suggest that you can know the machine learning, which means one word for one speech.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT, ok, I'll find out this.